# How do I pass the string from a textview to another texview on the same activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working with this bingo callboard project in Android Studio. The principle is when I click a number button, it will show on the first textview. When I click the second number button, the first textview will show the current number pressed and the previous string will be passed to the second textview. How would I do this? Screenshot of app included. A sample of the MainActivity.java code is here:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Activity mainActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainActivity = MainActivity.this;

        final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        final Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
        final Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
        final Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.b4);
        final Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.b5);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presentcall);
        final TextView lst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastcall);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button1.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B1");
                    if (button1.getText().equals("1"))
                {
                    button1.setText(" 1 ");
                    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button1.getText().equals(" 1 "))
                {
                    button1.setText("1");
                    button1.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button2.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B2");
                if (button2.getText().equals("2"))
                {
                    button2.setText(" 2 ");
                    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button2.getText().equals(" 2 "))
                {
                    button2.setText("2");
                    button2.setBackground(background);
                }

            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button3.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B3");
                if (button3.getText().equals("3"))
                {
                    button3.setText(" 3 ");
                    button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button3.getText().equals(" 3 "))
                {
                    button3.setText("3");
                    button3.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button4.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B4");
                if (button4.getText().equals("4"))
                {
                    button4.setText(" 4 ");
                    button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button4.getText().equals(" 4 "))
                {
                    button4.setText("4");
                    button4.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button5.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B5");
                if (button5.getText().equals("5"))
                {
                    button5.setText(" 5 ");
                    button5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button5.getText().equals(" 5 "))
                {
                    button5.setText("5");
                    button5.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSqjy.jpg)

Comment: You mean the "B5" should move below the "Last Call" area?

Comment: Exactly! How would I put it into code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so from what I understand you need to update the lst textview with the data of txt textView. Well you can write a common method which can be called from any button click with the new data. something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Activity mainActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainActivity = MainActivity.this;

        final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        final Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
        final Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
        final Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.b4);
        final Button button5 = findViewById(R.id.b5);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presentcall);
        final TextView lst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastcall);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button1.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B1");
                updateTextView("B1");
                    if (button1.getText().equals("1"))
                {
                    button1.setText(" 1 ");
                    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button1.getText().equals(" 1 "))
                {
                    button1.setText("1");
                    button1.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button2.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B2");
                 updateTextView("B2");
                if (button2.getText().equals("2"))
                {
                    button2.setText(" 2 ");
                    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button2.getText().equals(" 2 "))
                {
                    button2.setText("2");
                    button2.setBackground(background);
                }

            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button3.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B3"); 
                 updateTextView("B3");
                if (button3.getText().equals("3"))
                {
                    button3.setText(" 3 ");
                    button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button3.getText().equals(" 3 "))
                {
                    button3.setText("3");
                    button3.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button4.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B4");
                 updateTextView("B4");
                if (button4.getText().equals("4"))
                {
                    button4.setText(" 4 ");
                    button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button4.getText().equals(" 4 "))
                {
                    button4.setText("4");
                    button4.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Drawable background = button5.getBackground();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("B5");
                 updateTextView("B5");
                if (button5.getText().equals("5"))
                {
                    button5.setText(" 5 ");
                    button5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onclick_border);
                }
                else if (button5.getText().equals(" 5 "))
                {
                    button5.setText("5");
                    button5.setBackground(background);
                }
            }
        });
   }

    private void updateTextView(String newData){
    String oldData = txt.getText().toString();
    lst.setText(oldData);
    txt.setText(newData);
    }
}
```

This will update your last textview with your txt textview data. YOu can call this method from your button clicks with the new data as a parameter . Hope this helps you

Comment: There seems to be a problem. I inserted your code after my public void and nothing happens when I run it. Can you please walk me through it?

Comment: Have updated the above answer with places from invoking it. @brie

Comment: What happened was lst textview shows the same as txt textview on button click. I've been thinking, is probably because of (newData)?

Comment: Not sure..Can you share the entire updated code so that I can take a look

Comment: I am still working on the whole structure of the code. All I finished for now is the physical structure of my app and how it appears when I run it. Pretty much the code is the same as for the first five buttons since it's just simple buttons and textviews. The only complicated thing is this lst texview which I want to display what has been displayed on the txt textview.

Comment: Its no problem...just share your activity code with the code which I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with p.matthew13's code. The problem is with the code sequence. I may also have to delete a line on my code because it's already redundant.

The redundant code is `txt.setText("");` which contradicts `txt.setText(newData);`
I have to delete my setText code and replace it with the `updateTextView("");`
Also, I did place p.matthew13's code before my public void.

And that fixes my problem, after trying to shuffle up the code execution sequence.
Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it.You can upvote my answer if it helped you

Comment: You could edit the accepted answer. It helps anyone who refers to this question.